# Why does getDate() return Nan in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, calendar

This Javascript code creates a calendar of months and years and displays it on the screen. The code works perfectly in all browsers except Chrome. In Chrome, `lastDate.getDate();` returns `Nan` why?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Calendar of Events</title>
<style type="text/css">

#evtcal a:link {font: normal 12pt "Arial", "Helvetica", "Sans Serif"; color: #004400; text-decoration: none;}       /* unvisited link */
#evtcal a:visited {font: normal 12pt "Arial", "Helvetica", "Sans Serif"; color: #004400; text-decoration: none;}    /* visited link */
#evtcal a:hover {font: normal 12pt "Arial", "Helvetica", "Sans Serif"; color: #004400; text-decoration: underline;} /* mouse over link */
#evtcal a:active {font: normal 12pt "Arial", "Helvetica", "Sans Serif"; color: #004400; text-decoration: none;}     /* selected link */

</style>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="events.js"></script>

<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">

/* Preload images script */
var myimages=new Array()

function preloadimages(){
    for (i=0;i<preloadimages.arguments.length;i++){
        myimages[i]=new Image();
        myimages[i].src=preloadimages.arguments[i];
    }
}


/* The path of images to be preloaded inside parenthesis: (Extend list as desired.) */
preloadimages("images/PrevYrOff40x40.jpg","images/PrevYrOn40x40.jpg","images/PrevMoOff40x40.jpg","images/PrevMoOn40x40.jpg","images/NextYrOff40x40.jpg","images/NextYrOn40x40.jpg","images/NextMoOff40x40.jpg","images/NextMoOn40x40.jpg");


/***************************************************************************************
    JavaScript Calendar - Digital Christian Design
    //Script featured on and available at JavaScript Kit: http://www.javascriptkit.com
    // Functions
        changedate(): Moves to next or previous month or year, or current month depending on the button clicked.
        createCalendar(): Renders the calander into the page with links for each to fill the date form filds above.

***************************************************************************************/

var thisDate = 1;                           // Tracks current date being written in calendar
var wordMonth = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
var today = new Date();                         // Date object to store the current date
var todaysDay = today.getDay() + 1;                 // Stores the current day number 1-7
var todaysDate = today.getDate();                   // Stores the current numeric date within the month
var todaysMonth = today.getUTCMonth() + 1;              // Stores the current month 1-12
var todaysYear = today.getFullYear();                   // Stores the current year
var monthNum = todaysMonth;                     // Tracks the current month being displayed
var yearNum = todaysYear;                       // Tracks the current year being displayed
var firstDate = new Date(String(monthNum)+"/1/"+String(yearNum));   // Object Storing the first day of the current month
var firstDay = firstDate.getUTCDay();                   // Tracks the day number 1-7 of the first day of the current month
var lastDate = new Date(String(monthNum+1)+"/0/"+String(yearNum));  // Tracks the last date of the current month
var numbDays = 0;
var calendarString = "";
var eastermonth = 0;
var easterday = 0;


function changedate(buttonpressed) {
    if (buttonpressed == "prevyr") yearNum--;
    else if (buttonpressed == "nextyr") yearNum++;
    else if (buttonpressed == "prevmo") monthNum--;
    else if (buttonpressed == "nextmo") monthNum++;
    else  if (buttonpressed == "return") { 
        monthNum = todaysMonth;
        yearNum = todaysYear;
    }

    if (monthNum == 0) {
        monthNum = 12;
        yearNum--;
    }
    else if (monthNum == 13) {
        monthNum = 1;
        yearNum++
    }

    lastDate = new Date(String(monthNum+1)+"/0/"+String(yearNum));
    numbDays = lastDate.getDate();
    firstDate = new Date(String(monthNum)+"/1/"+String(yearNum));
    firstDay = firstDate.getDay() + 1;
    createCalendar();
    return;
}


function easter(year) {
// feed in the year it returns the month and day of Easter using two GLOBAL variables: eastermonth and easterday
var a = year % 19;
var b = Math.floor(year/100);
var c = year % 100;
var d = Math.floor(b/4);
var e = b % 4;
var f = Math.floor((b+8) / 25);
var g = Math.floor((b-f+1) / 3);
var h = (19*a + b - d - g + 15) % 30;
var i = Math.floor(c/4);
var j = c % 4;
var k = (32 + 2*e + 2*i - h - j) % 7;
var m = Math.floor((a + 11*h + 22*k) / 451);
var month = Math.floor((h + k - 7*m + 114) / 31);
var day = ((h + k - 7*m +114) % 31) + 1;
eastermonth = month;
easterday = day;
}


function createCalendar() {
    calendarString = '';
    var daycounter = 0;
    calendarString += '<table width="312" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">';
    calendarString += '<tr>';
    calendarString += '<td align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\"><a href=\"#\" onMouseOver=\"document.PrevYr.src=\'images\/PrevYrOn40x40\.jpg\';\" onMouseOut=\"document.PrevYr.src=\'images\/PrevYrOff40x40\.jpg\';\" onClick=\"changedate(\'prevyr\')\"><img name=\"PrevYr\" src=\"images\/PrevYrOff40x40\.jpg\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Prev Yr\"\/><\/a><\/td>';
    calendarString += '<td align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\"><a href=\"#\" onMouseOver=\"document.PrevMo.src=\'images\/PrevMoOn40x40\.jpg\';\" onMouseOut=\"document.PrevMo.src=\'images\/PrevMoOff40x40\.jpg\';\" onClick=\"changedate(\'prevmo\')\"><img name=\"PrevMo\" src=\"images\/PrevMoOff40x40\.jpg\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Prev Mo\"\/><\/a><\/td>';
    calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#C8C896\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"128\" height=\"40\" colspan=\"3\"><b>' + wordMonth[monthNum-1] + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + yearNum + '<\/b><\/td>';
    calendarString += '<td align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\"><a href=\"#\" onMouseOver=\"document.NextMo.src=\'images\/NextMoOn40x40\.jpg\';\" onMouseOut=\"document.NextMo.src=\'images\/NextMoOff40x40\.jpg\';\" onClick=\"changedate(\'nextmo\')\"><img name=\"NextMo\" src=\"images\/NextMoOff40x40\.jpg\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Next Mo\"\/><\/a><\/td>';
    calendarString += '<td align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\"><a href=\"#\" onMouseOver=\"document.NextYr.src=\'images\/NextYrOn40x40\.jpg\';\" onMouseOut=\"document.NextYr.src=\'images\/NextYrOff40x40\.jpg\';\" onClick=\"changedate(\'nextyr\')\"><img name=\"NextYr\" src=\"images\/NextYrOff40x40\.jpg\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Next Yr\"\/><\/a><\/td>';
    calendarString += '<\/tr>';
    calendarString += '<tr>';
    calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Sun<\/td>';
    calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Mon<\/td>';
    calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Tue<\/td>';
    calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Wed<\/td>';
    calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Thu<\/td>';
    calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Fri<\/td>';
    calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Sat<\/td>';
    calendarString += '<\/tr>';

    thisDate == 1;

    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        calendarString += '<tr>';
        for (var x = 1; x <= 7; x++) {
            daycounter = (thisDate - firstDay)+1;
            thisDate++;
            if ((daycounter > numbDays) || (daycounter < 1)) {
                calendarString += '<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#888888\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\">&nbsp;<\/td>';
            } else {
                if (checkevents(daycounter,monthNum,yearNum,i,x) || ((todaysDay == x) && (todaysDate == daycounter) && (todaysMonth == monthNum))){
                    if ((todaysDay == x) && (todaysDate == daycounter) && (todaysMonth == monthNum)) {
                        calendarString += '<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#AAFFAA\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\"><a href=\"javascript:showevents(' + daycounter + ',' + monthNum + ',' + yearNum + ',' + i + ',' + x + ')\">' + daycounter + '<\/a><\/td>';
                    }
                    else    calendarString += '<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFC8\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\"><a href=\"javascript:showevents(' + daycounter + ',' + monthNum + ',' + yearNum + ',' + i + ',' + x + ')\">' + daycounter + '<\/a><\/td>';
                } else {
                    calendarString += '<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#DDFFFF\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\">' + daycounter + '<\/td>';
                }
            }
        }
        calendarString += '<\/tr>';
    }

    calendarString += '<tr><td colspan=\"7\" nowrap align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#C8C896\" width=\"280\" height=\"22\"><a href=\"javascript:changedate(\'return\')\"><b>Show Current Date<\/b><\/a><\/td><\/tr><\/table>';

    var object=document.getElementById('calendar');
    object.innerHTML= calendarString;
    thisDate = 1;
}


function checkevents(day,month,year,week,dayofweek) {
var numevents = 0;
var floater = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        if (events[i][0] == "W") {
            if ((events[i][2] == dayofweek)) numevents++;
        }
        else if (events[i][0] == "Y") {
            if ((events[i][2] == day) && (events[i][1] == month)) numevents++;
        }
        else if (events[i][0] == "F") {
            if ((events[i][1] == 3) && (events[i][2] == 0) && (events[i][3] == 0) ) {
                easter(year);
                if (easterday == day && eastermonth == month) numevents++;
            } else {
                floater = floatingholiday(year,events[i][1],events[i][2],events[i][3]);
                if ((month == 5) && (events[i][1] == 5) && (events[i][2] == 4) && (events[i][3] == 2)) {
                    if ((floater + 7 <= 31) && (day == floater + 7)) {
                        numevents++;
                    } else if ((floater + 7 > 31) && (day == floater)) numevents++;
                } else if ((events[i][1] == month) && (floater == day)) numevents++;
            }
        }
        else if ((events[i][2] == day) && (events[i][1] == month) && (events[i][3] == year)) {
            numevents++;
        }
    }

    if (numevents == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


function showevents(day,month,year,week,dayofweek) {
var theevent = "";
var floater = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        // First we'll process recurring events (if any):
        if (events[i][0] != "") {
            if (events[i][0] == "D") {
            }
            if (events[i][0] == "W") {
                if ((events[i][2] == dayofweek)) {
                theevent += "Events of: \n" + month +'/'+ day +'/'+ year + '\n';
                theevent += events[i][6] + '\n';
                theevent += 'Start Time: ' + events[i][4] + '\n';
                theevent += 'Ending Time: ' + events[i][5] + '\n';
                theevent += 'Description: ' + events[i][7] + '\n';
                theevent += '\n -------------- \n\n';
                document.forms.eventform.eventlist.value = theevent;
                }
            }
            if (events[i][0] == "M") {
            }
            if (events[i][0] == "Y") {
                if ((events[i][2] == day) && (events[i][1] == month)) {
                theevent += "Events of: \n" + month +'/'+ day +'/'+ year + '\n';
                theevent += events[i][6] + '\n';
                theevent += 'Start Time: ' + events[i][4] + '\n';
                theevent += 'Ending Time: ' + events[i][5] + '\n';
                theevent += 'Description: ' + events[i][7] + '\n';
                theevent += '\n -------------- \n\n';
                document.forms.eventform.eventlist.value = theevent;
                }
            }
            if (events[i][0] == "F") {
                if ((events[i][1] == 3) && (events[i][2] == 0) && (events[i][3] == 0) ) {
                    if (easterday == day && eastermonth == month) {
                        theevent += "Events of: \n" + month +'/'+ day +'/'+ year + '\n';
                        theevent += events[i][6] + '\n';
                        theevent += 'Start Time: ' + events[i][4] + '\n';
                        theevent += 'Ending Time: ' + events[i][5] + '\n';
                        theevent += 'Description: ' + events[i][7] + '\n';
                        theevent += '\n -------------- \n\n';
                        document.forms.eventform.eventlist.value = theevent;
                    } 
                } else {
                    floater = floatingholiday(year,events[i][1],events[i][2],events[i][3]);

                    if ((month == 5) && (events[i][1] == 5) && (events[i][2] == 4) && (events[i][3] == 2)) {
                        if ((floater + 7 <= 31) && (day == floater + 7)) {
                            theevent += "Events of: \n" + month +'/'+ day +'/'+ year + '\n';
                            theevent += events[i][6] + '\n';
                            theevent += 'Start Time: ' + events[i][4] + '\n';
                            theevent += 'Ending Time: ' + events[i][5] + '\n';
                            theevent += 'Description: ' + events[i][7] + '\n';
                            theevent += '\n -------------- \n\n';
                            document.forms.eventform.eventlist.value = theevent;
                        } else if ((floater + 7 > 31) && (day == floater)) {
                            theevent += "Events of: \n" + month +'/'+ day +'/'+ year + '\n';
                            theevent += events[i][6] + '\n';
                            theevent += 'Start Time: ' + events[i][4] + '\n';
                            theevent += 'Ending Time: ' + events[i][5] + '\n';
                            theevent += 'Description: ' + events[i][7] + '\n';
                            theevent += '\n -------------- \n\n';
                            document.forms.eventform.eventlist.value = theevent;
                        }
                    } else if ((events[i][1] == month) && (floater == day)) {
                        theevent += "Events of: \n" + month +'/'+ day +'/'+ year + '\n';
                        theevent += events[i][6] + '\n';
                        theevent += 'Start Time: ' + events[i][4] + '\n';
                        theevent += 'Ending Time: ' + events[i][5] + '\n';
                        theevent += 'Description: ' + events[i][7] + '\n';
                        theevent += '\n -------------- \n\n';
                        document.forms.eventform.eventlist.value = theevent;
                    }
                }
        }
        }
        // Now we'll process any One Time events happening on the matching month, day, year:
        else if ((events[i][2] == day) && (events[i][1] == month) && (events[i][3] == year)) {
            theevent += "Events of: \n" + month +'/'+ day +'/'+ year + '\n';
            theevent += events[i][6] + '\n';
            theevent += 'Start Time: ' + events[i][4] + '\n';
            theevent += 'Ending Time: ' + events[i][5] + '\n';
            theevent += 'Description: ' + events[i][7] + '\n';
            theevent += '\n -------------- \n\n';
            document.forms.eventform.eventlist.value = theevent;
        }
    }
    if (theevent == "") document.forms.eventform.eventlist.value = 'No events to show.';
}


function floatingholiday(targetyr,targetmo,cardinaloccurrence,targetday) {
// Floating holidays/events of the events.js file uses:
//  the Month field for the Month (here it becomes the targetmo field)
//  the Day field as the Cardinal Occurrence  (here it becomes the cardinaloccurrence field)
//      1=1st, 2=2nd, 3=3rd, 4=4th, 5=5th, 6=6th occurrence of the day listed next
//  the Year field as the Day of the week the event/holiday falls on  (here it becomes the targetday field)
//      1=Sunday, 2=Monday, 3=Tuesday, 4=Wednesday, 5=Thurday, 6=Friday, 7=Saturday
//  example: "F",   "1",    "3",    "2", = Floating holiday in January on the 3rd Monday of that month.
//
// In our code below:
//  targetyr is the active year
//  targetmo is the active month (1-12)
//  cardinaloccurrence is the xth occurrence of the targetday (1-6)
//  targetday is the day of the week the floating holiday is on
//      0=Sun; 1=Mon; 2=Tue; 3=Wed; 4=Thu; 5=Fri; 6=Sat
//      Note: subtract 1 from the targetday field if the info comes from the events.js file
//
// Note:
//  If Memorial Day falls on the 22nd, 23rd, or 24th, then we add 7 to the dayofmonth to the result.
//
// Example: targetyr = 2052; targetmo = 5; cardinaloccurrence = 4; targetday = 1
//  This is the same as saying our floating holiday in the year 2052, is during May, on the 4th Monday
//
var firstdate = new Date(String(targetmo)+"/1/"+String(targetyr));  // Object Storing the first day of the current month.
var firstday = firstdate.getUTCDay();   // The first day (0-6) of the target month.
var dayofmonth = 0; // zero out our calendar day variable.

    targetday = targetday - 1;

    if (targetday >= firstday) {
        cardinaloccurrence--;   // Subtract 1 from cardinal day.
        dayofmonth = (cardinaloccurrence * 7) + ((targetday - firstday)+1);
    } else {
        dayofmonth = (cardinaloccurrence * 7) + ((targetday - firstday)+1);
    }
return dayofmonth;
}

</script>

</head>

<body style="background-color: transparent;" onload="changedate('return')">

<p align="center">Calendar of Events</p>

<center>
<table id="evtcal" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="584">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 3px;" align="center" bgcolor="#aaddff" valign="top" width="314">
                <div id="calendar"><!--  Dynamically Filled --></div>
                You can move to a different month or year by clicking on the buttons or return to today's date by clicking "Show Current Date".</td>
            <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="padding: 3px;" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffc8" valign="top" width="260"><b>Intructions:</b><br />Click a highlighted date on the calendar to see a list of events on that day in the box below.<br /><br />
                <center><b><u>Events</u></b>
                <form id="eventform" name="eventform" action="#" method="get">
                    <textarea name="eventlist" cols="25" rows="11" wrap="soft">Auto filled when clicking on date.</textarea>
                </form>
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</center>

<br />

<p style="font: normal 11px Arial" align="center">This free script provided by<br />
<a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

With your current logic you will end up having MonthNum = 13 (which will throw an error)

You have:

```
 var todaysMonth = today.getUTCMonth() + 1; // which will be = 12
 var monthNum = todaysMonth;  // so monthNum = 12
```

then you have this

```
 var lastDate = new Date(String(monthNum+1)+"/0/"+String(yearNum));
```

which will give you new Date("13/0/2015")

you have a both an invalid MONTH (13) and DAY

Comment: and why i have this issue only in chrome can you explain me that?

Comment: what does it return in IE or firefox?

Comment: do you want to give me your email so I can send you the html code and the js to check what it is doing in firefox where it works perfect and then run it in chrome and see the problem which I'm talking about?

Comment: you can just put it on jsfiddle.net or http://plnkr.co/edit/ and share the link, unless it contains come private content and data.

Comment: ok I used the jsfiddle.net that thes link:http://jsfiddle.net/p51fooeg/ you can see the issue? before the first day of a month the days are deleted after not and thats happened only in chrome and opera